# Add date to non-date numeric variable?

Tags: r, time-series

I am trying to show change over time in how the two political parties performed in US counties and why.

My data look something like:

```
County <- c("Franklin", "Rockham", "Smith", "Udall")
PopulationDensity <- c(63, 1250, 480, 129)
RepublicanPercent2000 <- c(42, 38, 62, 57)
DemocratPercent2000 <- c(54, 57, 34, 41)
RepublicanPercent2004 <- c(47, 35, 67, 44)
DemocratPercent2004 <- c(48, 64, 27, 49)
RepublicanPercent2008 <- c(44, 33, 64, 48)
DemocratPercent2008 <- c(55, 65, 31, 49)

PartisanData <- cbind.data.frame(County, PopulationDensity, RepublicanPercent2000, 
              DemocratPercent2000, RepublicanPercent2004, DemocratPercent2004,  
              RepublicanPercent2008, DemocratPercent2008)
```

Repeated for thousands of counties and dozens of elections. How can I show how county density affected the Democratic and Republican percentages over the course of time? I am relatively new to R, and I'm very stuck. I don't quite know how to conceptualize the solution.  All I can think of is creating a separate observation for each county for each year, but I'm not even sure that would allow an analysis of how density affected the votes and I'd like to be certain about that before creating a dataset with THAT many observations. My brain hurts.  Please help.

Thanks again!

Comment: Can you show the expected output

Comment: I would structure the dataframe to have the following columns: County, PopulationDensity, ElectionYear, RepublicanPercent, DemocratPercent. That would make it easy to compute correlations and other metrics. Also, for analysis and stats related questions, you'd probably have better luck here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `tidyr::pivot_longer`...

```
library(tidyr)

PartisanData %>% 
  pivot_longer(-c(1:2),                                  #don't pivot first two cols
               names_sep = "Percent",                    #split col names at "Percent"...
               names_to = c("Party", "Year"),            #...into Party and Year columns
               values_to = "percent")                    #name for value column

   County   PopulationDensity Party      Year  percent
   <fct>                <dbl> <chr>      <chr>   <dbl>
 1 Franklin                63 Republican 2000       42
 2 Franklin                63 Democrat   2000       54
 3 Franklin                63 Republican 2004       47
 4 Franklin                63 Democrat   2004       48
 5 Franklin                63 Republican 2008       44
 6 Franklin                63 Democrat   2008       55
 7 Rockham               1250 Republican 2000       38
 8 Rockham               1250 Democrat   2000       57
 9 Rockham               1250 Republican 2004       35
10 Rockham               1250 Democrat   2004       64
# ... with 14 more rows
```

It is then in a much easier form to filter or sort as required.

Answer (score 1):

I interpreted this as a visualization question, so I extended the provided solution to show you some visualization options for your data. Using a bubble chart (see https://www.r-graph-gallery.com/271-ggplot2-animated-gif-chart-with-gganimate.html), we can show population density, county, and voting percent by party on a single graph. Then, through facet_wrap or through the gganimate package, we can split the images based on year to properly visualize all data present in your example.

```
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(gganimate)

County <- c("Franklin", "Rockham", "Smith", "Udall")
PopulationDensity <- c(63, 1250, 480, 129)
RepublicanPercent2000 <- c(42, 38, 62, 57)
DemocratPercent2000 <- c(54, 57, 34, 41)
RepublicanPercent2004 <- c(47, 35, 67, 44)
DemocratPercent2004 <- c(48, 64, 27, 49)
RepublicanPercent2008 <- c(44, 33, 64, 48)
DemocratPercent2008 <- c(55, 65, 31, 49)

PartisanData <- cbind.data.frame(County, PopulationDensity, RepublicanPercent2000, 
                                 DemocratPercent2000, RepublicanPercent2004, DemocratPercent2004,  
                                 RepublicanPercent2008, DemocratPercent2008)

PartisanData <- PartisanData %>% 
  pivot_longer(-c(1:2),                                  
               names_sep = "Percent",                    
               names_to = c("Party", "Year"),           
               values_to = "percent")

electionVizGif <- ggplot(data = PartisanData, aes(County, percent, size = PopulationDensity, color=Party)) +
  geom_point(stat = 'identity') +
  theme_bw() +
  labs(title = "Year: {closest_state}") +
  transition_states(Year, transition_length=3, state_length = 1) + 
  ease_aes('linear')

electionVizWrap <- ggplot(data = PartisanData, aes(County, percent, size = PopulationDensity, color=Party)) +
  geom_point(stat = 'identity') +
  theme_bw() +
  facet_wrap(~Year) 

electionVizGif
electionVizWrap
```